# How to write type converter for a List<CustomObject> in room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have two entities 'tableOne' and 'tableTwo'

```
@Entity(tableName = "tableOne")
data class TableOne(
    @field:Json(name = "id") @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    @field:Json(name = "image") @ColumnInfo(name = "image") val image: List<Image>?
) {
    constructor() : this(0, null)
}

@Entity(tableName = "tableTwo")
data class TableTwo(
    @field:Json(name = "id") @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    @field:Json(name = "image") @ColumnInfo(name = "image") val image: List<Image>?
) {
    constructor() : this(0, null)
}
```

Now I have the 'Image' table which will be having the foreign key to the above two tables.

```
@Entity(
tableName = "Image",
foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
    entity = TableOne::class,
    parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
    childColumns = arrayOf("parent_id"),
    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
    onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
), ForeignKey(
    entity = TableTwo::class,
    parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
    childColumns = arrayOf("parent_id"),
    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
    onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
)]
)
data class Image(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = "parent_id") val parentId: Int,
    @field:Json(name = "url") @ColumnInfo(name = "url") val url: String?
) {
constructor() : this(0, 0, null)
}
```

I got an error when I ran the app.

```
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
```

How can we write type converter for List instead of converting to Json? Is this the way or do we need to add anything else?

```
    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    internal fun fromListOfImages(images: List<Image>): Image? {
        var img: Image? = null
        for (image in images) {
            img = image
        }
        return img
    }

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    internal fun toListOfImages(image: Image): List<Image> {
        val images: ArrayList<Image> = ArrayList()
        images.add(image)
        return images
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to write converter for your use case is

```
    @TypeConverter
@JvmStatic
internal fun fromListOfImages(images: List<Image>): String {
    return Gson().toJson(images)
}

@TypeConverter
@JvmStatic
internal fun toListOfImages(image: String): List<Image> {
    val listType = object : TypeToken<List<Image>>() {}.type
    return Gson().fromJson<List<Image>>(image, listType)   }
```

Comment: is there any way that instead of writing it as a JSON, can we keep it in separate tables and maintain the relationship?